# Can anybody explain this wired C++ code piece?

Tags: c++

```
#define WIRED\
  []() {\
    return new MyClass; \
  }()

MyClass* a = WIRED;
```

I don't understand the first `[]()` and the last `()` in the MACRO. Can any expert explain this? Thanks.

Comment: Seems like a long-winded way to say `new MyClass;`...

Comment: The macro `WIRED` defines a lambda, which returns a pointer to `MyClass`. This is just a ugly way to say `MyClass* a = new MyClass();`

Comment: This is an incredibly useless lambda and macro.

Comment: I will ask, where in this world did you get this weird piece of code?

Comment: Downvotes are harsh here. It's certainly an odd construct, but a clear token-by-token explanation would be of benefit to many people.

Comment: I asked this stupid question. I know its functionality. But I don't know this C++ grammer `[]()` and the last `()`

Comment: @user3796257 See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7627098/1870232)

Answer (score 4):

It's a lambda returning a dynamically allocate `MyClass` that is created and executed in place.

Specifically:

```
[](){...}
```

is the [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda); and the remaining `()` is the invocation of the lambda.

---

It's a useless lambda AFAIK and you can simply write:

```
MyClass* a = new MyClass;
```

or better:

```
std::unique_ptr<MyClass> ptr(new MyClass);
```

Comment: Of course, macros are ugly, and this could be done just as well with an inline function. It may be useless as-is, but I'd guess it was introduced to enable centralised changes to the code. Maybe it's in an `#ifdef` block which the OP didn't show - perhaps a different definition of `WIRED` is supplied when a specific macro (e.g. `DEBUG_ALLOCATIONS`) is defined.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to understand lambda function from C++11.

I believe you can understand this:

```
MyClass* CreateMyClass() { return new MyClass; }
...

std::function<MyClass* ()> creator_function = CreateMyClass;
MyClass* a = creator_function();
```

Then, lambda function seems like:

```
std::function<MyClass* ()> creator_function = []() { return new MyClass; };
MyClass* a = creator_function();
```

Finally, this would also work:

```
MyClass* a = []() { return new MyClass; }();
```